# Finding the rows along with the row number of first dataframe not found in second dataframe using Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking to check some large amount of data in GBs containing 2 CSVs. CSV files have no headers and also include only column which has some complex string mixture of numbers and alphabets like this

```
+--------------------------------+
| _c0                            |
+---+---------------------------+
| Hello | world | 1.3123.412 | B |
+---+----------------------------+
```

So far, I am able to converted into the dataframes but not sure , Is there any way to get the row numbers and rows of df1 not found in df2

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

file1 = 'file_path'
file2 = 'file_path'


df1 = spark.read.csv(file1)
df2 = spark.read.csv(file2)


df1.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: See my answer below. Does that help? Happy to assist further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets go step by step now that you are still learning
df1

```
+------------------------------+
|_c0                           |
+------------------------------+
|Hello | world | 1.3123.412 | B|
|Hello | world | 1.3123.412 | C|
+------------------------------+
```

df2

```
+------------------------------+
|_c0                           |
+------------------------------+
|Hello | world | 1.3123.412 | D|
|Hello | world | 1.3123.412 | C|
+------------------------------+
```

generate row numbers using a window function

```
df1= df1.withColumn('id', row_number().over(Window.orderBy('_c0')))

df2= df2.withColumn('id', row_number().over(Window.orderBy('_c0')))
```

Use a left semi join. These joins do not keep any values from the right datframe. They only compare values and keep the left dataframes values that are also found in the right dataframe

```
df1.join(df2, how='left_semi', on='_c0').show(truncate=False)

+------------------------------+---+
|_c0                           |id |
+------------------------------+---+
|Hello | world | 1.3123.412 | C|2  |
+------------------------------+---+
```

Comment: what about if we need to see the rows of df1 not found in df2.  How can we get the answer, |Hello | world | 1.3123.412 | B| as this record doesn't exist in df2

Comment: I think left_anti to be replaced by left_anti to get the records of df1 not found in df2

Comment: Read about `left_anti` and work it out. Reading Abit makes you learn coding faster